# wxPython Message Dialogs Shown Twice

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I've noticed that all my dialogs are being shown twice. So instead of them being destroyed immediately after the user presses 'OK', another message dialog pops up and the user has to press 'OK' again before it destroys.

A bit annoying considering that these dialogs can show up somewhat often.

Here is an example:

```
class windowClass(wx.Frame):

    def noBrowser(self, event):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self,
                               "Please choose a browser!",
                               "Error", wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()
```

This is part of a function in another class that calls this function...

```
if searchrow < numrows:
        try:
            search=startSearch(file)
            search.findDomains(searchrow, numrows, sheet, wbook, file)
            myClass.finderStarted=True
        except AttributeError:
             myClass.noBrowser(self)
```

myClass is an instance of the windowClass

Comment: Have you tried using `wx.MessageBox` instead?  It has pretty much the same arguments, but acts as a function that shows a `MessageDialog` then returns the result.

Comment: unable to duplicate ... if I copy your code (replace-ing self with None) it works fine ... that said you should just do `wx.MessageBox("Please Choose A browser","ERROR")` you should not need to "show" it as it should just work

Comment: Whether I use a MessageBox or MessageDialog I get the same result. See above for more code...

Comment: Can you provide a small runnable example that demonstrates the issue? Also what OS and wxPython version are you using?

Comment: This is wxPython 3.0 and im using windows. Don't think I would be able to provide a runnable example without posting my entire code...

Comment: you should be able to provide a runnable example ... it looks like that method gets called from an event Binding ....? but you are calling it excplicitly in at least one place ? what is event argument for? this code does not demonstrate your problem... ... but the answer to your question is __you must be calling nobrowser from multiple places ...__

Answer (score 0):

I called it twice...looks like it ws being called again later in the code.